# i want to compare names in two different tables and then equal get details

Tags: android

i have two different tables.I want to compare the names in two tables,if both the names are equal then i want to get the details.how can i do that? please help me.

Here is the code:

```
Cursor cr=mDbManager.fetchnewcustomerdata();
        Cursor cr1 = mDbManager.fetchinvoicecustomerdata();
        cr1.moveToFirst();
        //String address;
        while (!(cr1.isAfterLast())) {
            String name = cr1.getString(cr1.getColumnIndex("icstname"));
            if(name.equals(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("cname"))))
            {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"equal",1000).show();
            }
            String address = cr1.getString(cr1.getColumnIndex("caddress"));
            map.put(name, address);
            nameAList.add(cr1.getString(cr1.getColumnIndex("icstname")));
            cr1.moveToNext();
        }
        mDbManager.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think two ways it is possible

```
1) Either you need to establish relationship between those tables using the name column you are thinking of same between two tables.

2) Two separate queries to database, where condition for both queries will be the name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CursorJoiner

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the names are ordered .
 Then, sort it as the following sample:

```
 while( !eofInTable1 && !eofInTable2) {
        String name1 = getFieldFromTable1();
        String name2 = getFiledFromTable2();
        int tmpResult = name1.compareTo(name2);
        if(tmpResult == 0) {
             doYourAction();
             table1.moveToNext();
             table2.moveToNext();
        }
        else if( tmpResult == -1) {
           table1.moveToNext();
        }
        else {
           table2.moveToNext();
         }

  }
```